# How to know if Mongoose's upsert created a new document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this code in node.js/express.js:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var usersRouter = express.Router();
usersRouter.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
    req.body._id = req.params.id;
    var usr = new User(req.body);

    usr.validate(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({});
            return;
        }

        var upsertData = usr.toObject();
        delete upsertData._id;

        User.update({_id: usr._id}, upsertData, {upsert: true}, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({});
                return;
            }

            res.status(204).json({});
        });
    });
});
```

It works fine, but I would like to send a different response to the client if a new document has been created (status 201 with json in response body) or an existing one has been updated (status 204).

Is there a way to tell the difference from the callback of `User.update`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the third parameter from callback function:

```
...
User.update({_id: usr._id}, upsertData, {upsert: true}, function(err, num, n) {
  if (err) {
     res.status(500).json({});
     return;
   }

   if (!n.updatedExisting) { 
       /* new document */
   }

   res.status(204).json({});
});
...
```

`n` is an object like this:

```
{ updatedExisting: false,
  upserted: <ObjectId>,
  n: 1,
  connectionId: 11,
  err: null,
  ok: 1 }
```

`updatedExisting` property is `true` when a document *was updated* -- so it was created before. If it's `false`, then it means that the new document was created during this call.

Comment: That worked perfectly!
Thanks for the quick and clean answer!

Comment: @CarloVespa Cool! You're welcome. Now you should have vote privileges. :-) I upvoted you so you are 15+.

Comment: What if one is using exec() to turn into a Promise instead of using callbacks?

Comment: Yes a lot of these mongoose examples use the older callback signatures. Promises are where everything is heading it would be great to see mongoose embrace that at least in it's docs.