# Mongoose - Check if `upsert` made a new document or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there any way to know if Mongoose's `upsert` option made a new document or not **via await**? Essentially I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592128/how-to-know-if-mongooses-upsert-created-a-new-document) except without a callback.

Note: I'm using `findByIdAndUpdate`

Comment: This should work `const data = await User.update({ }, { upsert: true }) console.log(data)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet That would log the document contents

Comment: Then you are probably using `findOneAndUpdate`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am, `findByIdAndUpdate` to be exact, didn't know the return value would be different. Edited my question

Comment: Any reason to not use `update` and use @AnthonyWinzlet's convenient answer then?

Comment: @MadWard I could use it, was just hoping that other update functions supported it too. Anthony Winzlet, feel free to turn your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: @apxx Here one more you have missed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference in the `callback`, `async await` or even in with `.then` of mongoose functions

**Callback**

```
User.update({ _id: usr._id }, upsertData, { upsert: true }, function(err, num) {
  console.log(err)
  console.log(num)
}
```

**Async Await**

```
try {
  const num = await User.update({ _id: usr._id }, upsertData, { upsert: true })
  console.log(num)  
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

So basically both the above functions will log the same thing

Now what you want is to check whether the returned document is updated or upserted using `findOneAndUpdate` (findByIdAndUpdate)

```
const num = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, upsertData, { upsert: true })
console.log(num)
```

So here `num` will print either the document if it is already **exists** or **null** if it is been inserted.

Comment: Ooh you're right! Since the "old" doc wouldn't exist it'll just return `null` as the doc. Thanks!

Comment: Yes but don't use `new: true` :-)

Comment: @Ashh how can we know with `new: true` or is there a way to get the updated from num object return.